# Does using TLS make any sense when sending mail to localhost?

Tags: email, python-3.x, localhost, mail-server

I made a script in Python3 which sends emails to localhost, but I could not use TLS because it gave me the next error:

```
STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

I was trying to solve that, but then I thought about the question:

Does using TLS make any sense when sending mail to localhost?

I mean, you send your email in plain text to your localhost mail server, and this is the one in charge of encrypting the mail and send it via TLS, isn't it?

Comment: that question should be on super user I think.
and without the tag python.

Comment: Is there any option to migrate the question to Super User or do I have to copy and paste it?